Subtract certain rows based on duplicated cells in another column - Excel formula
I need to find the amount of days between each client visit. So, based on duplicated/matching IDs in column A, I'd like to subtract the related dates in column B, with the result in column C.

I've tried all combinations of 'if', 'sumifs', and 'countifs' formulas but I just haven't cracked it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please & thank you.


In cell C2, enter the following formula:
=IF(A2=A1, B2-B1, "")

Drag the formula in cell C2 down to apply it to all rows with visit dates.


